# Woocommerce Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Доброго времени суток! Спасите,помогите!
Кнопка есть но она не работает, страницу обновляет, но в корзину ничего не падает. А нужно чтобы при нажатии сразу переносить на оплату Paypal, но даже в корзину не падает. Вообще нужно сделать так чтобы Woocommerce воспринимала мой CPT "Films" как продукты, но я не знаю как. Есть ли какой то способ сделать это не связывая при этом CPT и Woocommerce Product? Вот листинг самого плагина

```html
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Films
Description: Declares a plugin that will create a custom post type displaying films.
Version: 1.0
Author: Kolomiets Igor
*/
do_action( 'woocommerce_register_post_type' );
add_action( 'init', 'create_film' );
function create_film() {
    register_post_type( 'films',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Films',
                'singular_name' => 'Film',
                'add_new' => 'Add New Film',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Film',
                'edit' => 'Edit',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Film',
                'new_item' => 'New Film',
                'view' => 'View',
                'view_item' => 'View Film',
                'search_items' => 'Search Film',
                'not_found' => 'No Film found',
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Film found in Trash',
                'parent' => 'Parent Film'
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'menu_position' => 15,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
            'taxonomies' => array( 'category' ),
            'menu_icon' => plugins_url( 'images/image.png', __FILE__ ),
            'has_archive' => true
        )
    );
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_admin' );
function my_admin() {
    add_meta_box( 'film_meta_box',
        'Custom attributes',
        'display_film_meta_box',
        'films', 'normal', 'high'
    );
}

function display_film_meta_box( $film ) {
    // Retrieve current name of the Director and Movie Rating based on review ID
    $subtitle = esc_html( get_post_meta( $film->ID, 'subtitle', true ) );
    $_price = esc_html( get_post_meta( $film->ID, '_price', true ) );
    ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100%">Subtitle</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="70" name="subtitle" value="<?php echo $subtitle; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100%">Price</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="40" name="_price" value="<?php echo $_price; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'add_film_fields', 10, 2 );
function add_film_fields( $movie_review_id, $movie_review ) {
    // Check post type for movie reviews
    var_dump($movie_review->post_type);
    if ( $movie_review->post_type == 'films' ) {
        // Store data in post meta table if present in post data
        if ( isset( $_POST['subtitle'] ) && $_POST['subtitle'] != '' ) {
            update_post_meta( $movie_review_id, 'subtitle', $_POST['subtitle'] );
        }
        if ( isset( $_POST['product_id'] ) && $_POST['product_id'] != '' ) {
            update_post_meta( $movie_review_id, 'product_id', $_POST['product_id'] );
        }
        if ( isset( $_POST['_price'] ) && $_POST['_price'] != '' ) {
            update_post_meta( $movie_review_id, '_price', $_POST['_price'] );
        }
    }
}

add_filter('woocommerce_get_price','reigel_woocommerce_get_price',20,2);
function reigel_woocommerce_get_price($price,$post){
    if ($post->post->post_type === 'films')
        $price = get_post_meta($post->id, '_price', true);
    return $price;
}
add_filter('the_content','rei_add_to_cart_button', 20,1);
function rei_add_to_cart_button($content){
    global $post;
    if ($post->post_type !== 'films') {return $content; }

    ob_start();
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input name="add-to-cart" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $post->ID ?>" />
    <input name="quantity" type="number" value="1" min="1" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Add to cart" />
</form>
<?php

return $content . ob_get_clean();
}
?>
```

Вот листинг шаблона

```html
<?php
 /*Template Name: New Template
 */
get_header(); ?>
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="content" role="main">
    <?php
    $mypost = array( 'post_type' => 'films', );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $mypost );
    ?>
    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <header class="entry-header" style="text-align:center">
                <!-- Display featured image in right-aligned floating div -->
                <div style="float: right; margin: 10px">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </div>
                <!-- Display Title and Author Name -->
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                <h4><?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'subtitle', true ) ); ?></h4>
                Price: <?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_price', true ) ); ?>
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <input name="add-to-cart" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $post->ID ?>" />
                    <input name="quantity" type="number" value="1" min="1"  />
                    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Add to cart" />
                </form>
                <?
                    var_dump(get_button_code_for_product(get_the_ID()));
                ?>
                <br />
            </header>
            <!-- Display movie review contents -->
            <div class="entry-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
        </article>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WooCommerce [использует только один custom post type - product](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/installed-taxonomies-post-types/).

Так что не получится подсунуть пост с типом `films` вашему магазину. Скорее всего, любые попытки скрестить функционал WC и CPT обречены на провал.

Comment: То есть нужно делать отдельно новый Post и новый Product и их связывать?

Comment: Я не вижу, как их связать.

Comment: по мете. Вот я получаю продукт к которому привязан    $product = get_product(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'product_id', true ));                                  а вот кнопка покупки <? echo "<button><a href='" . $product->add_to_cart_url() ."' style='color:#FFF'>Buy in one click</a></button>";?>       Такой себе костылик

Comment: ну так-то можно - тогда у Вас две сущности: пост в CPT и пост в WC. Я имел ввиду, что не вижу возможности объединить функции двух плагинов в одной сущности (одной записи кастомного типа).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь